# Why is std::unique_ptr<> not working in this specific case?

Tags: c++, mysql

So I learned the benefits of using `std::unique_ptr`. I tried that for MySQL and having some errors. I tried to narrow it down. What is causing this?

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> stmt_prepared;

stmt_prepared = conn->prepareStatement("SELECT content FROM books WHERE title = ?;");
```

The first `=` is getting a compile-time error:

> "No operator '=' matches these operands."

`prepareStatement()` returns a pointer to `sql::PreparedStatement`.

If it matters, the `PreparedStatement` class has pure virtual functions.

Some more info on the class:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html

Comment: It would be `reset`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: try `std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> stmt_prepared(conn->prepareStatement("SELECT content FROM books WHERE title = ?;"));`

Comment: construction from pointer should be explicit. it is done to avoid easy mistake.

Comment: @Jarod42: Alternatively, using the [make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) function template allows you to invoke [unique_ptr::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D).

Comment: @IInspectable: `make_unique` cannot be used there, as we don't use `new` directly. (Ideally, we would want that `prepareStatement` return `unique_ptr` directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` doesn't define a copy assignment operator that takes a raw pointer. Instead you can use the `reset` function to call the destructor and free the currently held object (in this case there is none), and then store the passed object.

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> stmt_prepared;
stmt_prepared.reset(conn->prepareStatement("SELECT content FROM books WHERE title = ?;"));
```

If you wan't to construct the `unique_ptr` with a value:

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> stmt_prepared(
    conn->prepareStatement("SELECT content FROM books WHERE title = ?;")
);
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah yes my bad

Comment: A friend suggested reset() "creates a foo, then destroys that foo and replaces it with a new foo." Sounds expensive.

Comment: However, those are the only two choices besides just using a pointer and deleting them (probably fastest with a database).

Comment: @Bob What *foo* is `reset` creating and destroying? In the example you've shown `stmt_prepared` initially contains `nullptr`, so there's nothing to destroy. If it already contained a `PreparedStatement*` then of course `reset` would first destroy it, else you'd be leaking the resource. If `unique_ptr::operator=(T*)` existed, that would also do the same as `reset`. If you don't want the existing resource to be destroyed, call `release` first. Your time would be better spent reading [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of listening to bad advice.

Comment: Advice says you apparently has some arbitrary distinction between 'destroying" and "calling the destructor"